# Return value of a stored procedure in C# returns error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve the return value of a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 as follows:

```
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(process_name, connection);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < process_parameters.Length; i++)
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(process_parameters[i].ParameterName, process_parameters[i].Value);

        //Add output param
        comm.Parameters.Add("@TestID", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When ExecuteNonQuery() is called, however, I get back a **OleDbException** saying: **"Procedure or function myStoredProcedure has too many arguments specified."**  My stored procedure begins as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTabtempTestsINSERT]
(
            @Param1     char (64),
            @Param2     char (128),
            @Param3     char (64),
)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare     @TestID         int
```

And ends with the following:

```
    RETURN @TestID
END
```

Does the fact that the return value is declared, rather than being passed as a parameter, have anything to do with it?  If so, how can I get the return value of a param that's declared after the stored procedure begins?  Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:
I've tried the changes suggested so far, I added the following line:

```
            OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(process_name, connection);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            for (int i = 0; i < process_parameters.Length; i++)
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(process_parameters[i].ParameterName, process_parameters[i].Value);

            var testID = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Now when `ExecuteScalar()` gets executed, I get a **NullReferenceException** with **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

Note: I also tried setting it to an integer `int testID = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();` and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to get it to work properly.  My problem was that, I neglected to declare any of the parameters as OUTPUT, I added an extra variable and set that as the output variable and had the stored procedure return that.  After word I just checked that output parameter ,after calling the stored procedure, from my C# code, the following shows the changes:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTabtempTestsINSERT]
(
            @Param1     char (64),
            @Param2     char (128),
            @Param3     char (64),
            @ReturnValue int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare     @TestID         int
```

And at the end make a simple change:

```
    SET @ReturnValue = @TestID
    RETURN @ReturnValue
END
```

Finally, back in my code:

```
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(process_name, connection);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    for (int i = 0; i < process_parameters.Length; i++)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(process_parameters[i].ParameterName, process_parameters[i].Value);

       //Add output param
        comm.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Stored Procedure returned a value of "+ comm.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value); //Success
```

Thank you all for your suggestions.  Any alternatives or further insights are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
 comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to

```
 int returnValue =  (int) comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

And remove:

```
  comm.Parameters.Add("@TestID", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't return anything from SQL..... am I missing something here?

Comment: If there actually was an OUTPUT parameter in the proc definition, then he could use ExecuteNonQuery and just read the new parameter value.  However, the OP was a little mixed up

Answer (score 0):

remove these:

```
 //Add output param
        comm.Parameters.Add("@TestID", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and use this instead: `var testID = (int) comm.ExecuteScalar();`

Answer (score 0):

In response to the accepted answer...

Because you are setting the parameter's `Direction` to `ReturnValue` here:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

You don't need an `OUTPUT` parameter in your stored procedure at all. You could change it back to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTabtempTestsINSERT]
(
        @Param1     char (64),
        @Param2     char (128),
        @Param3     char (64),
)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare     @TestID         int
```

With:

```
    RETURN @TestID
END
```

at the end and it would still work exactly as it does now.

It is *purely coincidental* that your `ReturnValue` `Parameter` in C# bears the same name as your `OUTPUT` parameter. There is a separate parameter `Direction` for `OUTPUT` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem is that you have to declare the return parameter **first** (before the input and output ones), this way it works:

```
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(process_name, connection);
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//Add the return param first
comm.Parameters.Add("@TestID", OleDbType.Integer).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

for (int i = 0; i < process_parameters.Length; i++)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(process_parameters[i].ParameterName, process_parameters[i].Value);

comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
Object return_value = comm.Parameters["@TestID"].Value;
```